# AutoLayout with Multiple Images in XCode

Tags: swift, xcode, autolayout, constraints

I'm trying to use autolayout in XCode to position these two images like they are in the screenshot, but when I run the simulator, they're in the wrong position. Here is basically what I want to do:

- scale the images up if the screen size goes up (and vice-versa)
- have the dog picture just above the middle of the screen
- have the loading picture a certain distance below the dog (i.e: loading.y = dog.y +         screenheight/4)

I have not gotten the hang of autolayout yet so any direction to what constraints I should use would be appreciated.

[Image of View Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBVLP.png)

Comment: You have not told us anything about what your constraints are. There are 10000000 ways to do this wrong and basically one way to do it right, so how can we guess which of the wrong ones is yours?

Comment: show us your code (it should be compilable) and tell us exactly what you want. read and consider this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @matt I haven't added any constraints- that's what I'm asking. I don't know what to add.

Comment: @Chris I haven't written any code yet I'm trying to get these images positioned using autolayout and storyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would ***really*** benefit from just spending time reading through auto-layout tutorials / articles / discussions / documentation / etc.

Here is an example of what you are describing.

Using these two images:

[image]

[image]

You can lay out your image views in Storyboard like this:

[image]

The dog imageView has:

- Centered horizontally
- Bottom constrained 90% to the CenterY position (just above the middle)
- Width is 50% of the safe-area width
- Height determined by Aspect Ratio of 236:175 (the original size of the image)

The loading imageView has:

- Centered horizontally
- CenterY constrained 1.75% to the CenterY position (effectively screenHeight / 4)
- Width is 75% of the safe-area width
- Height determined by Aspect Ratio of 368:76 (the original size of the image)

and here is how it looks on 3 different device sizes:

[image]

The best way to learn this is to just work on it.

Comment: Thank you! Very thorough and thoughtful answer.